# Access Grails mysql database through grails console?

Tags: mysql, grails

I know that in Ruby on Rails you can easily access the database in production (on the remote server) by running `rails -c` and setting the environment to Production.

Is it possible to do the same in Grails ? Or do I need to do it locally form my machine given I have my remote production database in the `DataSource` set up ?

Thanks

Comment: What type of access are you talking about? Pure SQL queries or just loading up your application context (but not the web container/tomcat) and being able to evaluate code against the production data source?

Comment: the second one. "just loading up your application context (but not the web container/tomcat) and being able to evaluate code against the production data source?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with [grails console](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/ref/Command%20Line/console.html)

Comment: but I will need top have my code on the server right ?

Comment: If you have your grails project on your local machine you should be good.